# Converting MVC2 to MVC3 and pages to Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

First and foremost reason to update big old MVC2 project for me is the Razor engine. Now following [this instructions](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) 
I successfully converted the project without yet touching .aspx and .ascx files.

1) Can you guys tell me now, how can I convert Master pages to layouts, and start converting pages and user controls without breaking any existing MVC2 pages? (it's a large project, can't do them all at once). Can I somehow use old master pages as layouts in razor pages?

I converted a couple of partial aspx pages which don't use a master page.
I used Telerik's aspx2razor converter - it helps although you still have to do a lot of manual revisions.

2) Is there any other better tool out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Razor and the normal views side by side. By default, MVC3 looks for razor first, then will fall back to the WebFormsViewEngine.

So you should have no problem, and you can tackle each page in time as you see fit.

Comment: I know that... My question is how can I reuse old masterpages in razor pages

Comment: It can be converted straight to a layout page. Really, it's mostly going to be changing `<% blah %>` to `@blah`. You would want to convert the master page to the appropriate layout with the same name, and then it should all magically work again.

Comment: Covert the Master page to a Layout page, but don't get rid of the original master page until everything that uses it has been converted to razor.

Comment: should I keep a copy of a master page. Or I can just convert it into .cshtml and delete the old one?

Comment: They can be present side by side. The cshtml will look for the layout cshtml by convention / configuration, and the aspx will look for the .master

Comment: still I guess there should be some manual how to do that right... "asp:ContentPlaceHolder", "inherits" and other statements, what about them, should I replace them with new stuff?

Comment: `@RenderBody` and `@RenderSection("footer")` depending on your use